# R - How to subtract multiple columns into one

Tags: r, dataframe

Good afternoon,

I am pretty new to R and I can't seem to find the answer to my question. Give a dataframe with multiple columns, I would like to subtract all the column values accross the rows into a final column. Example:

Initial dataframe:

| Column A | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ex1 | 10 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| ex2 | 25 | 12 | 3 | 2 |
| ex3 | 1 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| ex4 | 7 | 2 | 9 | 10 |

Desired output:

| Column A | e |
| --- | --- |
| ex1 | -8 |
| ex2 | 8 |
| ex3 | -23 |
| ex4 | -14 |

I suppose it should be easy but as I said I am not very experienced. Thanks.

I tried -rowSums(), but it actually first sums the values and just add the negative sign at the end value.

Answer (score 3):

You are right to use `rowSums()`:

```r
# Select columns to subtract
cols <- c("b", "c", "d")

data.frame(
    `Column A` = dat$`Column A`,
    e = dat$a - rowSums(dat[, cols]),
    check.names = FALSE
)
#   Column A   e
# 1      ex1  -8
# 2      ex2   8
# 3      ex3 -23
# 4      ex4 -14
```

Comment: I was just assuming that putting the - in front of the function would subtract all the columns indexed inside the function itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can try `Reduce`

```
> cbind(df[1], e = Reduce(`-`, df[-1]))
  Column A   e
1      ex1  -8
2      ex2   8
3      ex3 -23
4      ex4 -14
```

## data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(`Column A` = c("ex1", "ex2", "ex3", "ex4"), a = c(10L,
25L, 1L, 7L), b = c(5L, 12L, 7L, 2L), c = c(6L, 3L, 8L, 9L),
    d = c(7L, 2L, 9L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to sum the whole row, but subtract the sum of all columns except the first, from the first column. Assuming your data frame is called `df`:

```
df$e <- df[,1] - rowSums(df[,-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoy `rowwise()` for row level operations as the intuition is very strong.

1. add rowwise() to your dataframe
2. mutate a new column as a list and directly write the desired operations
3. unnest the newly created column
4. optionally ungroup afterwards

```
library(tidyverse)

# replicate your dataframe
dat <- tibble(
    Column.A = c("ex1", "ex2", "ex3", "ex4"),
           a = c(10L, 25L, 1L, 7L),
           b = c(5L, 12L, 7L, 2L),
           c = c(6L, 3L, 8L, 9L),
           d = c(7L, 2L, 9L, 10L)
)

# add new column

dat |> 
  rowwise() |> # will group by rows
  mutate(
    e=list(a-b-c-d) # add new column as list -- directly type the operation
  ) |> 
  unnest(e) # unnest the results
```

alternatively you can use pmap from the purrr package

```
library(tidyverse)

dat |> 
  mutate(
    e=pmap(
      list(a,b,c,d) # you must list the columns by their names in a list
      ,.f=\(a,b,c,d){ # anonymous function
        a-b-c-d
      }
         
         )
  ) |> 
  unnest(e)# similiar need to unnest the results
```

Comment: What if you had 200 columns? you will have to list all of them by name? Do you see how innefficient this method is?

Comment: yes -- certainly for a 200 column use case this wouldn't be efficient -- if using this approach, I'd suggest some meta programming to generate a string with "action" to be perfromed then execute it with some combination of expr() / eval() (I think).

Comment: I think every approach has a weakness / drawback -- eg. if you only wanted to subtract even pairs or odd pairs or every 5th or columns starting with "A" or whatever the irregular logic is. I believe all solution can be adapted towards that solution just some are more efficient than others depending on the use case

Comment: No thats not the point. Every approach has a weakness is a fallacy. Note that OP has multiple columns. you assumed only 4, but that is not generalizable. which makes this method incorrect. This is hard coded solution. You should always have a teachable heart and accept when you are incorrect rather than try to defend something that is hard coded. Look at the way my comment was made. it was made in terms of questions, to enable you see that something was wrong. Sorry if it made you uncomfortable and defensive

Comment: hey I appreciate your response and agreed with your comment in my opening line Regarding the assumptions - I didn't make any assumptions to the number of columns, I merely responded to the OP using the example case taking into account any criteria / constraints that were provided. As you correctly note, every case as a weakness -- but that doesn't make it invalid. The answer meets the criteria provided.  I find rowwise and pmap to be valid applications for row level operations but to your point may not be the most efficient.  I appreciate your response -- it is helpful for my learning journey